# Architecture Server-Client using Azure Services

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

could you give me some advice to establish an architecture for the next scenario using the Azure services?

[image]

1. From Central Server, I need to be able to send messages only if the Agent i is online.
2. I need to receive confirmation to know if a message was delivered or not
3. The communication is One-way Central Server to Agent i
4. Can be multiple agents in the future
5. The correct order of messages must be guaranteed

i is any agent 1 to x

I was thinking to use Azure Service Bus, but I'm not sure if this is the best strategy. I could to have a queue for each agent, but according what I saw in the examples, I can not receive confirmation when a message was delivered, In addition I didn't see any function to know if a receiver is online or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario is more towards real-time acknowledgement and it would be difficult using service bus. Have your considered "Azure SignalR Service" for this?